# Array editing in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

Ive been working on an app for android much alike the program "Powder Toy". In order to simulate particle "stacking" I have an array that monitors every column and if a particle goes past the value of the corresponding element, it is stopped and the element is increased for the next particle to land a little higher. When the element is changed it doesn't just change by one, instead I got numbers changing from, for example: 320 to -1211, 320 to -602, 320 to 14, and so on. I might be missing something basic about array editing, any ideas how to get around this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < intspan; i++){
    tempx = particlex[i];
    tempy = particley[i];

    if(tempx == 0 && tempy == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        canvas.drawPoint(tempx, tempy, paint);

        if(tempy < columns[tempx]) {

            particley[i] += 1;
        }
        else if (tempy >= columns[tempx]){
            columns[tempx]--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I change the element by ONE and instead the result is drastically changed

Comment: Do you have any example code that you could provide?

Comment: Okay I don't think the explanation conveys enough of the problem, could you post some relevant code and highlight the erroneous output?

Comment: Do you have multiple functions accessing the same Array at the same time? If that is the case you might be getting threading / concurrency issues which are always fun. And by fun I mean not fun at all.

Comment: This is my first post on stack, I'm having trouble posting the code, no matter how much I change it, it tells me its not properly formatted, I'm very sure its only being accessed once. Every frame albeit, but still only one function.

Comment: There we go, the code posted is the code that actually changes the array

Comment: @Nick okay, now what is the problem with the code posted, what is not getting the output you expect after a run?

Comment: The array "columns" is changing drastically, though the code shows it's changed by a value of one.

Comment: How do you inspect these values? It could be the index that changes, and therefore leads you to see the next particle instead of the current one

Comment: I logged the value of each element in the array, and the problem when it runs is that since the values changed so drastically, instead of stacking, the particle freezes in the air because "tempy" is >= "columns[tempx]"

Answer (score 0):

In the part

```
else if (tempy >= columns[tempx]){
    columns[tempx]--;
}
```

Your are decreasing columns[tempx], when it is *smaller* than tempy.
Therefore it is getting smaller and smaller.
And as it is inside a for loop, it could be decreased by up to the number of your particles in a single run.